# CMake find_path include directory prefix

Tags: c++, cmake, openni

I am writing a minimal Find*.cmake for OpenNI. To find the header files I wrote

```
find_path(OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH XnOS.h)
```

which is working as expected (OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH has the value /usr/include/ni). 
However, in my files I have to include the headers with

```
#include <ni/XnOS.h>
```

How can I get rid of the ni prefix, so I can write

```
#include <XnOS.h>
```

The problem with the first include is that a XnCppWrapper.h gets included and this file includes again some Xn*.h headers, but without the ni prefix. This results in a compiler error.

Comment: Are all of the files in the first form? I mean you could adjust the OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH variable to be the parent of what is returned by find_path() and use that instead.

Comment: I think, I don't get your suggestion. Do you mean that I should strap ni from /usr/include/ni? This doesn't solve the include problem.

Comment: I mean if ni is in /usr/include then OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH should be /usr/include instead of /usr/include/ni. This way you do not need to generate some script process that changes your c++ source files and headers looking for includes to remove the path. Although I do know if this was the case /usr/include will allready be in your includes so the OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH would be redundant.

Comment: Although you could always set(OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH ${OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH};${OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH}/..)

Comment: You are right, ni is in /usr/include. Unfortunatley it doesn't change a thing if I change OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH to be /usr/include. In either case I have to write #include <ni/XnOs.h> in my files, which results in the above described compilation error.

Comment: If /usr/include is in your includes "#include <ni/XnOs.h" should not result in a compile error. Although I do not have a lot of experience with gcc.

Comment: It results in a compilation error, because in the file XnOs.h is again an include that doesn't have the ni/ prefix. Then the compiler complains that it can not find the file.

Comment: Then try to include both paths like I said 3 posts ago.

Comment: That was no solution. I get the same compilation error.

Comment: If both /usr/include/ni and /usr/include are in your includes you should not get an error. Something else must be happening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Always have the path you use for `find_path` match the one in your `#include` statements.

If you want to `#include <ni/XnOS.h>` you should write

```
find_path(OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH ni/XnOS.h)
```

If instead you want to `#include <XnOS.h>`, use

```
find_path(OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH XnOS.h)
```

Just be sure to make up your mind beforehand which one you want to use and *stick to it*. Mixing several include paths for the same library is a sure way to unnecessarily overcomplicate the build environment.

Comment: In my cmake file I have `find_path(OPENNI_INCLUDE_PATH XnOS.h)` and I want to include the header with `#include <XnOS.h>`, but it doesn't work this way.

Comment: @Masala Then you probably have a bug in your CMake script somewhere. Use [`message`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:message) to verify that the value returned by `find_path` matches your expectation. Also be sure to double-check that your targets actually use that value as an include directory.

Comment: You were right, the mistake was in the main cmake file and not in the find module.